# PHP echo in foreach does not printing uniformly?

Tags: php, foreach, xampp, localhost, echo

### Update my source page at the bottom

In my PHP foreach echo "printing", only the first row of the output keeps all printed values in one horizontal row, begin by 2nd output row, I don't know why it separates into new rows.

My foreach code:

```
          foreach ($feedback as $item): 
            echo '<div class="card my-3 w-7">';
            echo '<div class="card-body text-center">';
            echo $item['custid'],str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), $item['cakeid'], str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), 

            "<form action='index.php' method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='cake_button' value='".$_SESSION['c'] = $item['cakename']."'>
            </form>",

            str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), $item['ordertime'], str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), 
            $item['pickuptime'], str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), $item['pricepaid']; 
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
          endforeach;
```

My foreach is inside an if-statement function, see this is the entire code block:

```
        <?php if (!empty($_POST['body'])){
          echo '<div class="card my-3 w-7">';
          echo '<div class="card-body">';
          echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 75),"CustID", str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3),"CakeID", str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3),
          "Cake Name", str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), "Order Time", str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3),
          "Pickup Time",str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), "Price Paid";
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          foreach ($feedback as $item): 
            echo '<div class="card my-3 w-7">';
            echo '<div class="card-body text-center">';
            echo $item['custid'],str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), $item['cakeid'], str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), 

            "<form action='index.php' method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='cake_button' value='".$_SESSION['c'] = $item['cakename']."'>
            </form>",

            str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), $item['ordertime'], str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), 
            $item['pickuptime'], str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3), $item['pricepaid']; 
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
          endforeach;
          
}
```

[image: screenshot]This is the screenshot I took, as you can see, the format is not consistent. I would like to have every rows look like the first row. I run this website from my local host through XAMPP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Leave Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-4">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Database draft</a>
  </div>
</nav> 


<main>
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <img src="/db/feedback/img/logo.png" class="w-10 mb-3" >
    <form method="POST" action="/db/feedback/index.php" class="mt-4 w-75">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="body" class="form-label">Check Order for Cake Bakery</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="body" name="body" placeholder="Enter your Customer ID"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-dark w-100">
      </div>
  </div>


        <form action="/db/feedback/index.php" method="POST"></form>

    </form>
</main>

<footer class="text-center mt-5">
  Updated: 2022/04/27
</footer>
 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you view the source in the browser, what does it show? Is everything opened and closed correctly?

Comment: @aynber I do not see anything stranger, but I update my question, if you want to take a look at the source.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you do `$_SESSION['c'] = $item['cakename']` inside the loop? That keeps replacing the session variable, and the final value will just be the last item.

Comment: Seeing the source with the cakes would help more. The code you posted does not have that. However, your close form tag is in the wrong spot .. it's after the second form instead of inside the container div

Comment: I think what you're seeing is just bootstrap's resposive layout due to the way the text fits into the line.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I forgot to remove that session assignment sorry for the confusion...I was testing if i could put a session assignment to be a button's name and can still assign to the session array. lol..

Comment: @aynber thanks for pointing out, I'm very new to php...and after i move the close form tag now my printing uniformly... all breaking up like my 2nd and 3rd rows... i will try to study more about it... but thank you, i prefer uniformity even its broken uniformity....

Comment: This is not how to present tabular data; it really should be in a table, as in the answer provided below. Even if you weren't putting it in a table, this is not a typewriter. You can't just put a bunch of spaces in and expect it to line up – that's what Bootstrap's columns are for. But again, you should be using a table. You should also take note of the [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and short echo tags `<?= ?>` that the answer uses. Outputting HTML with `echo` is not sustainable.

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Use table format instead of div class card **

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['body'])): ?>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CustID</th>
            <th>CakeID</th>
            <th>Cake Name</th>
            <th>Order Time</th>
            <th>Pickup Time</th>
            <th>Price Paid</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($feedback as $item): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $item['custid']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $item['cakeid']; ?></td>
                <td><form action='index.php' method='post'>
        <input type='submit' name='cake_button' value="<?= $_SESSION['c'] = $item['cakename']; ?>">
        </form></td>
                <td><?= $item['ordertime']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $item['pickuptime']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $item['pricepaid']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like he's creating a bootstrap grid rather than using an ordinary table. Bootstrap is generally preferable because it's responsive.

Comment: @Barmar except they are clearly presenting tabular data, so should be using a table, semantically speaking.

Comment: Grids are commonly used to display tabular data, but they're much more flexible.